# Grammar role of letting in this sentence : I'm thinking about **letting** Emma have her first cookie

Tags: grammar

Here is a sentence from Freinds Tv series:

> I'm thinking about **letting** Emma have her first cookie.

I can't understand why we should use `letting` instead of simply using `let`.

What is the grammar behind this?

Answer (score 1):

The structure is

> I'm thinking about "something"

You need a noun phrase for "something". So you can say "I'm thinking about flowers" or "I'm thinking about the first time that we met"

A gerund ("letting") can also be a noun phrase, so "I'm thinking about letting Emma have her first cookie" can be correct grammar.  Infinitives can also be noun phrases, but this particular sentence needs a gerund, "letting", not an infinitive, "to let.